# Should Iterator.hasNext be side effect free?

Tags: java

I am writing an iterator that iterates over a list of lists by delegating to the "current" lists own iterator. (No I'm not, but this is a simple example). Now, when I reach the end of one list, I need to update the delegate to point to the next lists' iterator. Can I do this in "hasNext"? Or is it better to implement in "next" prior to returning to the caller? I feel "hasNext" should better be side effect free. What's your opinion on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be OK for `hasNext` to have side effects as long as they are not perceptible from the outside. Above all, it must be **idempotent**. It is in fact often the case that `hasNext` can't know whether there is a next without fetching it, and, even if it could "unfetch", it is OK to cache.

Comment: +1 You should be able to call `hasNext()`, zero, one or twice per `next();`

Answer (score 3):

Guava's [`Iterators.concat`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat%28java.util.Iterator%29) does that. From the javadocs, it:

> `public static <T> Iterator<T> concat(Iterator<? extends Iterator<? extends T>> inputs)`
>
> Combines multiple iterators into a single iterator. The returned
>   iterator iterates across the elements of each iterator in {@code
>   inputs}. The input iterators are not polled until necessary.

If you look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java) you will see that the `hasNext` method changes the `current` iterator to the next iterator i.e. it is not free of side effects, so this approach is ok.

Comment: So if I forget to call hasNext() before next() I could get a NoSuchElementException that would not be thrown had I called hasNext before?

Comment: No, `next()` will always call `hasNext()` (or at least its logic) internally.